# how delete squiggly folder in sub directory

Tags: linux

Im trying  to delete folder, i dont know why it was can create..
i have already try rm -rf ~ , but it delete root folder

```
how to delete    ~     (squiggly folder in sub directory) folder 
below the path


# pwd
/root/data/xmpp-php/xmpphp
# ls -ltr
total 56
-rw-r----- 1 root root  1819 Jan  9 19:18 webclient_example.php
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Jan  9 19:18 tests
-rw-r----- 1 root root  1647 Jan  9 19:18 cli_longrun_example_bosh.php
-rw-r----- 1 root root  2688 Jan  9 19:18 cli_longrun_example.php
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Jan  9 19:18 XMPPHP
-rw-r----- 1 root root  1686 Jan  9 19:18 README
-rw-r----- 1 root root 18390 Jan  9 19:18 LICENSE
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root  4096 Jan  9 19:18 .svn
-rw-r----- 1 root root   637 Jan 10 00:41 ~               i want to delete this folder
-rw-r----- 1 root root   640 Jan 10 01:14 sendmessage_example.php
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a "folder" (a.k.a directory) - it's a plain file. Perhaps `cd /root/data/xmpp-php/xmpphp; rm ./~`. Tilde expansion only occurs when it's the first character of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following command:

---

```
cd /root/data/xmpp-php/xmpphp
rm -rf \~
```

---